# How do I resolve link problems mask PHP /"////"//"/"

Tags: php, sql, hyperlink, cpanel, mask

I have a website, using tiny_mce backoffice.
My website works well on my server, but I have to change the host server and suddenly I see this problem:

For example:

If I want to save text with links, for wikipedia.org for example... And I save on backoffice (with open new window propertie _target)

-Then in website interface, I click on wikipedia text link
and and instead of opening a new window, I have somethinfg like this :

```
mysite.com//"//"////"http://wikipedia.org/"////"//"/"
```

Is that normal?
Last server never happen that
And in this new server he creates somethink like a mask
anyone knows how to resolve that?

thanks 
best regards

Answer (score 0):

You should use `stripslashes();`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php

***EXAMPLE***

```
<textarea class="tiny_mce"><?php echo stripslashes(); ?></textarea>
```